# Failure of Building a PostgreSQL Docker image from Dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, dockerfile, docker-image

I cannot build a Docker image of Postgresql from its' official [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/c5d3ed25bad6c9977cc6ef8dfebb07dabdb40763/13/bullseye/Dockerfile).

My environments is Ubuntu20.04 on a Hyper-V on Windows11 and Docker version is 23.0.1.
I ran following command from a terminal since I put a Dockerfile  in the directory. Adding `sudo` does not work either.

`docker image build -t pg13:org .`

```
[+] Building 1.0s (18/18) FINISHED                                                                                           
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                    0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 10.11kB                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim                                                 0.7s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                         0.0s
 => [ 1/14] FROM docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim@sha256:8eaee63a5ea83744e62d5bf88e7d472d7f19b5feda3bfc6a2304cc0  0.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim@sha256:8eaee63a5ea83744e62d5bf88e7d472d7f19b5feda3bfc6a2304cc074  0.1s
 => CACHED [ 2/14] RUN set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /dev/null; then   apt-get update;   apt-get install -y --no-ins  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/14] RUN set -eux;  groupadd -r postgres --gid=999;  useradd -r -g postgres --uid=999 --home-dir=/var/li  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/14] RUN set -eux;  savedAptMark="$(apt-mark showmanual)";  apt-get update;  apt-get install -y --no-ins  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/14] RUN set -eux;  if [ -f /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker ]; then   grep -q '/usr/share/locale' /etc/dpkg/  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/14] RUN set -eux;  apt-get update;  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends   libnss-wrapper   xz-ut  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/14] RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/14] RUN set -ex;  key='B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8';  export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)";  mk  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/14] RUN set -ex;   export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1;   dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)";  aptRep  0.0s
 => CACHED [10/14] RUN set -eux;  dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert "/usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample.dp  0.0s
 => CACHED [11/14] RUN mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql && chown -R postgres:postgres /var/run/postgresql && chmod 2777 /v  0.0s
 => CACHED [12/14] RUN mkdir -p "/var/lib/postgresql/data" && chown -R postgres:postgres "/var/lib/postgresql/data" &&  0.0s
 => CACHED [13/14] RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [14/14] COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/                                                             0.0s
------
 > [14/14] COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/:
------
Dockerfile:191
--------------------
 189 |     
 190 |     RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
 191 | >>> COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
 192 |     ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
 193 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref moby::xi8hqbyz8wxzjv9rw6y4jrsc5: "/docker-entrypoint.sh": not found
```

I added line #190 because chmod of sh file sometimes works, but chmod command seems fine and copy command failed.

Does someone know how to resolve this?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed the path in the COPY? Because it looks like it expects to find it at /

Comment: Only modification I did was adding line #190. I tried `COPY /docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/:` but same error happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I managed to get an error on the same line here (running in an ubuntu 20.04 lxd container rather than a vm, but same setup).

Are you missing the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file? If I delete that file from my directory I get an error on the same line. Otherwise, the build goes through. It's not the same error as yours - yours suggests a bad path / missing directory.

All I did was download the files from the `postgres/13/bullseye` directory and run the command you gave. This was in a new ubuntu-20.04 container with docker installed from the ubuntu repos.

Comment: I searched the `docker-entrypoint.sh` at first place on the Ubuntu but there was no such a file. Where was your `docker-entrypoint.sh` in your Ubuntu? I thought that the file is made during building along w/ a Dockerfile. Am I wrong?

Comment: No - the COPY command copies files from your local machine into the image. Click that link to the `Dockerfile` you posted and then click on the `bullseye` directory. Download the docker-entrypoint.sh you see to the same directory as your Dockerfile and hopefully it will work.  Normally you would use a pre-built image or download the whole repo.

Comment: It is successfly built. Thank you!